# tslint: prefer-for-of Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, tslint

I am getting this tslint error:

```
prefer-for-of  Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop with this simple iteration
```

code:

```
function collectItems(options) {
    const selected = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      const each = options[i];
      if (each.selected) {
        selected.push(each.label);
      }
    }
    return selected;
  }
```

Can somebody help me to understand and resolve this error?
I know there an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243048/tslintexpected-a-for-of-loop-instead-of-a-for-loop-with-this-simple-iterat) on this question but that's not helping in my situation.

Comment: Why is the other question not helping?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `for-of` which iterates over the elements of an array to avoid the ts-lint warning:

```
function collectItems(options) {
    const selected = [];
    for (const each of options) {
        if (each.selected) {
            selected.push(each.label);
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```

Or you can use a one liner to filter the array:

```
const selected = options.filter(e=> e.selected).map(e=> e.label);
```

Answer (score 6):

`for-of` is much more terse and doesn't require manual iteration. The linter is recommending that you write something like this instead, for the sake of readability:

```
function collectItems(options) {
  const selected = [];
  for (const each of options) {
    if (each.selected) {
      selected.push(each.label);
    }
  }
  return selected;
}
```

But it would be even better to use `reduce` in this situation:

```
const collectItems = options => options.reduce((selectedLabels, { selected, label }) => {
  if (selected) selectedLabels.push(label)
  return selectedLabels;
}, []);
```

(You could also use `filter` followed by `map`, but that requires iterating over the array twice instead of once)